# Python Dependecies for DataprocCreateBatchOperator

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, airflow, dataproc

Cannot submit Python job onto dataproc serverless when third party python dependencies are needed. It's working fine when dependencies are not needed. I push up the pyspark python file to a cloud storage bucket and then the DataprocCreateBatchOperator reads in that file. I was hoping I can just pass in a list of pip packages but this might not be baked into the operator.

From the docs, dataproc serverless offers a [metadata](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.DataprocCreateBatchOperator) option which I presumed is how we inform dataproc to install additional python dependencies but its not working as seen below.

**DAG**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocCreateBatchOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

PROJECT_ID = "foobar"
REGION = "us-central1"
IMPERSONATION_CHAIN = "demo@foobar.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
BUCKET = "gs://my-bucket"
JOB="countingwords.py"

BATCH_CONFIG = {
    "pyspark_batch": {
        "main_python_file_uri": f"{BUCKET}/python/latest/{JOB}",
        "args": ["gs://pub/shakespeare/rose.txt", f"{BUCKET}/sample-output-data"]
    },
    "environment_config": {
        "execution_config": {
            "network_uri": f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/global/networks/main-vpc-prd",
            "subnetwork_uri": f"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/regions/{REGION}/subnetworks/data-prd",
            "service_account": IMPERSONATION_CHAIN,
        }
    }
}

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="serverless_countwords_py",
    start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    submit_serverless = DataprocCreateBatchOperator(
        task_id="submit_batch",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region=REGION,
        batch=BATCH_CONFIG,
        gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        metadata={'PIP_PACKAGES':'requests'}, ## <--- ISSUE
        impersonation_chain=IMPERSONATION_CHAIN,
    )

    submit_serverless
```

**Error**

`Failed to execute job 103 for task submit_batch (too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

**Other Thoughts**

Maybe I can somehow just zip my dependencies up and dump into a bucket and then dataproc can just read that zip? The BATCH_CONFIG.pyspark_batch has an additional field named python_file_uris where maybe I can just passed in a zipped file location containing all the dependencies. Unsure on the list of commands to achieve this zipped approach